# pdo bindParam with associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, associative-array

I am trying to bindParams with an associative array, looped through a foreach, but I dont get it to work somehow. I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

here is the code. The var `$columns` and `$values` comes from the array as well, manipulated so its accepts them like `x, x, x` and `:x, :x, :x`

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data($columns) 
VALUES ($values)");
foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{
    $key = ":" . $key;
    $stmt1->bindParam($key, $value);
    $stmt1->execute();  
}
```

I am pretty sure the columns are macthing the keys in the array.

EDIT: more of the code

```
$values = '';
$columns = implode(',', $array);
foreach($array as $key)
{
    $values .= ":" . $key . ",";
}
$values = substr($values , 0, -1);
```

Comment: Insufficient code to provide proper judgement. Show the `$values` at least.

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen sorry, i've edited the question with the code

Comment: Still `$array` is a mystery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes because you are executing the query at each iteration, but it is stopped at first because of the error. When it does execute at first iteration you actually bound only one variables and one token so the count is wrong and you get the error. You just need to move the execution out of the loop

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $key = ":" . $key;
   $stmt1->bindParam($key, $value); 
} 
$stmt1->execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

You are calling execute with the every iteration, so it is fired with only one variable actually bound.

Instead of that loop just pass your array into execute

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data($columns) VALUES ($values)");
$stmt1->execute($array);
```

Also, your code is [prone to sql injection through column names](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).